# how to pass an argument jquery and return the function value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just learning the ropes with jQuery and I am trying to create the front end for a simple FizzBuzz game, I have a function as follows...

```
FizzBuzz.prototype.play = function(number){
    if (this.isDivisibleByFifteen(number)) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    }
    else if (this.isDivisibleByThree(number)) {
        return "Fizz"; 
    }
    else if (this.isDivisibleByFive(number)) {
        return "Buzz";
    }
    else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

I wish to have a an html form which excepts the param `(number)` and returns the outcome within a span container...

````
<form id="game">
      <input type="text" name = "text" placeholder="Type your number"/>
</form>

<span id="outcome">??</span>```
````

Here is what I have so far, tear apart as you please...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#outcome").text(function() {
        fizzBuzz.play( $(this).attr("number") );
    });
});
```

Obviously this doesn't take into account any input from the form, but not really to sure how to do that yet.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use .prototype only if you are adding functionality to an existing prototype.

So you first have to define a prototype:

```
function fizzBuzz(){
// here you can define properties and methods (such as play method)
};
```

than you can add new functionalities if necessary

```
fizzBuzz.prototype.play = function(number){
    if (this.isDivisibleByFifteen(number)) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    }
    else if (this.isDivisibleByThree(number)) {
        return "Fizz"; 
    }
    else if (this.isDivisibleByFive(number)) {
        return "Buzz";
    }
    else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

You should define the fizzBuzz on a new javascript file and than include that file on your view.

Than you define your view elements with ids' or classes so you can select them later:

```
<form id="game">
      <input type="text" id="number" name = "text" placeholder="Type your number"/>
</form>

<span id="outcome">??</span>
```

than you can create an object of fizzBuzz and than call its methods:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myGame = new fizzBuzz();

    $("#number").change(function() {
        var number = $(this).val(); // get the number from text element
        // you probably want to validate if $(this).val() is a number.
        var result = myGame.play(number); 

        $("#outcome").text(result); // set the text of outcome = result.

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the outcome value on load. You need to capture some event in order to run the game when the user has provided a value, for example as you haven't got a button, here's how you can do it on key up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#game input[name=text]").keyup(function() {
        $('#outcome').text(fizzBuzz.play( this.value ));
    });
});
```

Or if you want to run the game when the user presses the enter key (i.e submitting the form):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#game").submit(function() {
        $('#outcome').text(fizzBuzz.play( $('input[name=text]', this).val() ));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this-

```
$('#game').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var requiredText = fizzBuzz.play( $(this).find("input").val() );
  $('#outcome').text(requiredText);
})
```

Since, you have created a form. You need to enter any value in the input field and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var val1 = $("#game").find('.game').val(); #you need a class="game" for this in your input html
   $("#outcome").text(var1);
```

You might need to parseInt your val1, because it probably goes through as a string:

```
parseInt(val1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! You just missed a `return` in your filler function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#outcome").text(function() {
        return fizzBuzz.play( $(this).attr("number") );
    });
});
```